# Installing a Module in DNN , Folder permissions

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

- I am trying to install a module in a DNN project residing on Godaddy.
- I am getting an error installing the module
- I know the error I am getting in DNN is coz of permissions.
- I thought giving write permissions to the App_Data and DesktopModules folder will resolve the error, but it doesn't, is there any other folder I have to give write permission to
- BTW, I am trying to install the already existing "Feedback" module in DNN

Comment: can you give more details, exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: Well the error is not very constructive|and looks something like this http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/8094/dnn.png
I might even look at the event viewer and let u know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the Feedback module and most modules that are installed as PA's have binary/compiled files for the data provider and much of the actual code for the controls. First thing I would check is that the 'bin' folder has write permissions as well as 'app_code' and 'desktopmodules'